# What does a null value from db2 look like when it is retrieved from C code?

Tags: c, database, null, db2

Currently, I am able to retrieve values from IBM DB2.  What I needed to be able to do is see what that value looks like if it is null.

In my code I set up a conditional statement that checks for most null values except I apparently do not know what a null value would like if it is retrieved from DB2 in my C code.

Currently I have:
if(pchr == NULL || pchr == "Null" || 
        pchr == "NULL" || pchr == '\0' || pchr == “null”)

where pchr is a character pointer.

Apparently this conditional statement cannot detect the null value from DB2.  Any help would be awesome

Comment: Without further knowledge: That should be documented in the API definition.

Comment: `pchr == "Null" || pchr == "NULL" || pchr == “null”` ..these are string matching. DB2 returns NULL. And how are you storing values in pchr. Pl. provide your query for that

Comment: What does the debugger say? Which value does `pchr` have? Would have been easier than posting a question. Note: `pchr == "NULL"` is not how string compare works in C.

Comment: @Cyclotron3x3: The first term will catch that already.

Comment: As @Olaf said you'll need to look at the API.  However in general you should expect that DB2 will usually have a null indicator in the struct that the API call will populate.  So you'd need to check that indicator to determine whether the value in question is NULL.

Comment: Also if you're writing a CLI or ODBC application that is fetching string data, note that the length argument will have the value `SQL_NULL_DATA`  if the column's value is NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Null is *usually* indicated with a separate variable.  For [DB2](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.embed.doc/doc/t0005636.html) embedded SQL, it looks something like this:

```
EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
  VARCHAR pchr[PCHR_LEN+1];  /* nullable field we're interested in */
  short   pchrInd;           /* flag indicating field is currently null */
EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;
...
EXEC SQL SELECT phcr INTO :pchr:pchrInd FROM table; // or SELECT pchr INTO :pchr INDICATOR :pchrInd
if ( pchrInd )
  // pchr is null
else
  // process pchr
```